# Select rows from SQL table where ALL of a set of parameters exist in joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following SQL Server schema:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (Id int);
CREATE TABLE #TableB (Id int, TableA_Id int, Status_Id int)
CREATE TABLE #Statuses (Id int)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN #TableB AS B
        ON A.Id = B.TableA_Id
    INNER JOIN #Statuses AS S
        ON B.Status_Id = S.Id
```

How can I get all the rows in `TableA` for which there are at least one entry of each of the rows in `dbo.Statuses`?

For example, in the following set of data only row 2 of `#TableA` should be returned:

```
#TableA
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]

#Statuses
[1]
[2]
[3]

#TableB
[1][1][1]
[2][1][3]
[3][2][1]
[4][2][2]
[5][2][3]
[6][3][1]
```

Comment: Search for LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT B.TableA_Id
FROM #Statuses S
LEFT JOIN #TableB B
    ON B.Status_Id = S.Id
GROUP BY B.TableA_Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT S.Id) = COUNT(DISTINCT B.Status_Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a "simple" `where` clause.  Assuming that the status column in `#TableB` only has valid status values:

```
select a.*
from #TableA a
where (select count(*) from statuses) = 
      (select count(distinct status) from #TableB b where b.TableA_Id = a.id);
```

You can relax this assumption.  Here is one way:

```
select a.*
from #TableA a join
      (select count(*) as numstatuses from #statuses) s
where (select count(distinct b.status)
       from #TableB b join
            #statuses s
            on b.id = s.id
       where b.TableA_Id = a.id
      ) = numstatuses
```

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e94e/14/0):

```
SELECT TableA_Id
FROM TableB
GROUP BY TableA_Id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Statuses);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I didn't mention is that TableB may have duplicates, meaning that if you have 4 of the same it will still return that row even though it does not contain ALL the unique values

Comment: A DISTINCT would solve it, but Lamak already gave that answer. Thanks again